# How to quickly remove unnecessary sounds in FCPX?

Tags: audio, final-cut-pro-x

I'm editing audio in Final Cut Pro X; I have exported the audio from Davinci Resolve because FCPX has a variety of equalizers and noise reduction built-in.

In this audio, I am talking but I occasionally smack my lips together and make other unpleasant sounds.  So, I am trying to remove them as fast as possible.

I realize that there is no good way to automatically identify them, so I am listening to the track and, when I hear an unneeded sound, making four keyframes using `ALT+K` as shown in the photo:

[image: audiokeyframes]

This isn't too difficult to do but it is a little inconsistent for the following reasons:

- After I make the four keyframes with the keyboard shortcut, I have to select the middle two keyframes to pull the audio down with the mouse, and making this selection is tricky sometimes even with the timeline zoomed in.
- When I pull down the audio, it's usually about -30 db, but it's hard to precisely line up; when I do this several times per file, I am unlikely to make them all exactly the same.  This probably isn't a big deal but it is inconsistent.
- There's no way (I can tell) to copy-and-paste sets of keyframes.

Is there a faster way to do this, or is what I'm doing about as good as it gets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 methods that might help with this.

1. Press the I and O keys to mark a range around the audio you want to fix. Then press CTRL+OPT+L and type a number value for the amount you want to the audio to drop (eg:-60db)
2. Make your keyframes, select them, then OPT+SHIFt+C to copy them, then OPT+SHIFT+V to paste them where you need them.

Method 1 is probably more flexible as you can customise the range if need be.

[image: Method 1]

[image: Method 2]

Comment: Thanks, it's much faster to make the keyframes with in-out points and then adjust the curve/handles manually than to do all of them with ALT+K.